# How to split string by a series of uppercase words with regex

Tags: python, regex, split, substring

Giving a text like this :

```
text= "THE TEXT contains uppercase letter, but ALSO LOWER case ones. This is another sentence."
```

I want an output something like this -->

```
['THE TEXT contains uppercase letter, but', 'ALSO LOWER case ones. This is another sentence.']
```

How can i write a regex to obtain that output?

I tried with this regex `"(\b[A-Z][A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][A-Z]+)*\b)"` but the output was differnt:

```
[ '',
 'THE TEXT',
 'contains uppercase letter, but',
 'ALSO LOWER',
  'case ones. This is another sentence.']
```

Comment: What you're saying is very unclear, maybe state the input and the expected output clearly.

Comment: unclear about the output demo, why 'This is another ...' doesn't come with a new string?

Comment: because i want to split my text only after words composed by all uppercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can match and extract them with

```py
re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]{2,}(?:\s+[A-Z]{2,})*\b.*?(?=\s*\b[A-Z]{2}|$)', text, re.DOTALL)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJGfEr/1).

*Details*:

- `\b[A-Z]{2,}(?:\s+[A-Z]{2,})*\b` - word boundary, two or more uppercase letters, zero or more repetitions of one or more whitespaces, two or more ASCII uppercase letters and a word boundary
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\b[A-Z]{2}|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces, word boundary and two uppercase letters, or end of string.